# Unable to run queries in SQL Lab in Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

[image][image]

I'm unable to run queries in SQL Lab. As soon as I run the query, Result sections shows {e} and query history says failed. Attaching the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this one by looking through dev tools for exact exceptions. 
This one has to do with the Signal alarms. Since superset is not supported with Windows, you will need to pass the exceptions on enter and on exit methods in core.py. It should be located in the file ~ C:\python\venv\Lib\site-packages\superset\utils

Comment Try in the below method and add pass:
def **enter**(self):
def **exit**(self, type, value, traceback):

Comment: Hey, are you trying to make the question like a Q&A, or did you just answered your question by researching after posting the question? I'm just curious

Comment: I was stuck at this question but then resolved it by following the error stack :) Thanks!